# Dropdown is present on top right side and when clicked shows items on top left side

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

**Issue Details**

Dropdown is present on top right side and when clicked shows items on top left side.

**How to replicate it?**

Please maximize the window. It will replicate only in maximized window.

What I have done so far?

**[I have js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sv8k0y6x/)**

**Here is the code**

```
<div id="app">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Company name</a>
            <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
                <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Welcome User
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-left" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                              <span data-feather="home"></span>
                              Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>

                    <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                        <span>Saved reports</span>
                        <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
                        </a>
                    </h6>
                </div>
              </nav>
            <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center mb-3 border-bottom">
                   @yield('content')
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line of code

```
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-left" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="">
```

into this to get it working using native Bootstrap functions

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="">
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1tc7wxnh/

And some more information about Menu Alignment in Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `_dropdown.scss` includes the following style `left: 0`.

You have to overwrite it using for instance the following additional css:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
}
```

This will place your dropdown items on the right side as desired.

You can either place it in your personal css file or use it inline a `<style>` element or directly on your element `<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="left: inherit; right: 0;<">`